# Which files in $HOME defines the user preferences in gnome?

Tags: gnome, backup, dot-files

I'm backup/syncing my dotfiles in my $HOME-Directory via git. I don't want to sync everything of course, so I ignore everything via .gitignore and re-add the important files.

```
*

!.bash*
.*.swp
.bash_history
.bash_local
.bash_logout
!.profile
```

Which files are necessary to back up in an Ubuntu Gnome environment which belongs to the system settings, like user-specific preferences or theme settings?

Comment: Most of it is stored in a binary database (gsettings/dconf, look in `~/.config/dconf`), so it's not suitable for Git.

Comment: @Olorin why not?

Comment: @StephenKitt if you're OK with keeping binary files with possibly frequent changes in Git, go ahead.

Answer (score 6):

Since GNOME settings are generally stored via the GSettings API, and some of those files are binaries/databases, your best bet is to rely on `dconf` tool:

**To export settings:**

```
dconf dump / > dconf-settings.ini
```

**To import settings:**

```
dconf load / < dconf-settings.ini
```

You could save the contents of `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dconf`(most of the time, it represents `~/.config/dconf`) but that would not be suitable for `git` since those files are not plaintext.

This Gnome Settings export will also contain all settings related to [Mate Desktop](https://mate-desktop.org/) and [Cinnamon Desktop](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/) since they are objects inside the root schema ( `/` ). To export those desktops settings only:

**Cinnamon:**

```
 dconf dump /org/cinnamon/ > dconf-cinnamon.ini
```

**Mate:**

```
dconf dump /org/mate > dconf-mate.ini
```

**Backup custom themes.**

To backup your custom themes/icons, compressing the folders `~/.icons` and `~/.themes` should be enough. Maybe you should keep the original theme files you already have at your home dir...

Comment: It would be better using `gsettings` instead of `dconf`, which is more portable and reasonable. `gsettings` use schema id while `dconf` as low-level implementation detail use schema path.

Comment: And how would you export all Gnome configurations using a one-liner wth `gsettings`? Do you have an example since, even inside Gnome Documentation `dconf` seems to be the right tool to dump configurations while `gsettings` is only to set, monitor and get those values? - https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-gsettings/ - Also, this document has no examples so, it's hard to see `gsettings` as the adequate tool for this task...